# termQuery not returning results

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When i use QueryBuilders.matchQuery method, all the matches that contains the given value returns, but i only want to return an exact value. I searched that it can be resolved by using termQuery method instead of matchQuery, but it returned nothing. How can i do only return the exact matched string?

val sourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder()
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("external_reference", id))

```
        val searchRequest = SearchRequest()
        searchRequest.indices(elasticIndex)
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder)

        var searchResponse: SearchResponse?
        searchResponse = esClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
```

Answer (score 0):

term queries are not analyzed, and you need to use it on the `.keyword` fields, if your Elasticsearch index mapping is generated by Elasticsearch than in the new Elasticsearch versions, every `text` field will also have `.keyword` field, so you need to use

```
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("external_reference.keyword", id))
```